# prevent render server from sleeping

Tags: node.js, cron

I got a node app hosted on a render server, and as it's under the free tier, it sleeps after 15m of inactivity, and I wrote a cron job using the node-cron package. if the app is asleep, the node-cron functions won't be active. is there any way to keep my render app awake?

I've used Heroku and Kaffeine (for keeping heroku apps awake)

are there any alternatives for Render?

Answer (score 10):

Use https://console.cron-job.org/ and setup an HTTP call after every 14 minute.

Comment: thanks, I actually fixed this by using node-cron on the server itself and self-pinging every 10 minutes, turned out pretty well and my server hasn't slept since then. I'll keep this site in mind tho, whenever I wouldn't want to write my own cron jobs :)

Comment: I won't advise pinging the server every 10 minutes. You'll run out of free hours on your free plan in a few days.

Comment: @Odunsi Render spins down a Free web service that goes 15 minutes without receiving inbound traffic, so there is no need to ping the server every 10 but 15 minutes. Also, Render grants 750 Free instance hours to each user and team per calendar month. 30 days * 24 hours = 720 hours.

Comment: @VicTør  you used your own server's cron job to ping the your service itself, that is a good solution but its not a good way since you are adding a dependent code for it. Also cron-job.org provide notification and auto retry facility without any cost. Can you also mark my answer as accepted if you think its worthy.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lambda function and schedule it to trigger every `N` time and ping your server to keep it listening to incoming traffic, also you can see the log and monitor the of your function

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 const url = 'https://yoursitehere.onrender.com';

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const req = https.get(url, (res) => {
     if (res.statusCode === 200) {
       resolve({
         statusCode: 200,
         body: 'Server pinged successfully',
       });
     } else {
       reject(
         new Error(`Server ping failed with status code: ${res.statusCode}`)
       );
     }
   });

   req.on('error', (error) => {
     reject(error);
   });

   req.end();
 });
};
```