# How can I start deployed server on Render from my front end application

Tags: reactjs, rest, render

Recently, I created an app which has separately REST API and React. I have deployed the REST API on Render and the React (create-react-app) on Firebase. My problem is that I use a free plan on Render and my REST server becomes inactive after 15 minutes. Thus, when opening the React app it loads fine but doesn't make the requests since the REST API is turned off.

This gets fixed when I go to Render and click on the link to start the server. Unfortunately, this is not efficient and I want to ask if there is any way that I can start the server (from being inactive) upon loading of the client application.

Comment: I see some resume service api for render. Maybe call this api in your react app on first load? https://api-docs.render.com/reference/resume-service-1

Comment: @david have you found a workaround? One way to go around it is on the homepage to 'ping' the server, like if you have verifyUser controller? If you don't, then just build a route handler that does nothing at '/ping' endpoint so when User enters your React app this request will be made. And for any request that receives a status 500 response -> just alert the User 'Wait for my server to wake up'.

Comment: @David I found a rather better alternative using cron job to ping your server every 14 minutes, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75680364/12737879).